# The beta-function lemma (in Boolos and Jeffrey) without primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, computability

Boolos and Jeffrey in *Computability and Logic* (3rd ed.) give a proof of the Beta-function Lemma (14.2, pp. 162-3) that makes use of the idea that any finite sequence of natural numbers: $i_0, ..., i_k$ (for any $k$) can be "encoded" into (and then "decoded" from) some ordered pair of natural numbers <*p, q*> such that:

$p$ is prime and ($p-1$) > $i_0, ..., i_k, k$;

$q = (p-1) *_p 0 *_p i_0 *_p (p-1) *_p 1 *_p i_1 *_p ... *_p (p-1) *_p k *_p i_k$,

where 'a $*_p$ b' is the result (denoted in base-$p$ notation) of concatenating $a$ and $b$ numerals in base-$p$ notation ('$*_p$' associates to the left).

[Then, any $j$-th (for 0 $\leq j \leq k$) member of the sequence can be "decoded" from <*p, q*> by an appropriately defined Beta-function.]

Question(s): Is the use of primes necessary in this case? What if $p$ were any number such that ($p-1$) > $i_0, ..., i_k, k$?